# I am trying to override bootstrap css with a custom page but my custom overrides aren't showing up. My custom css doesn't work at all

Tags: java, css, spring, intellij-idea, bootstrap-5

[Picture of intellij idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvR2N.png)
I have been awake for a long time and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point but my custom css file does not work at all, even if I comment out the bootstrap css.

I have been googling what to do for over an hour and I tried a lot of the recommendations but nothing is working so far. I tried using !important; I had my custom css link both above and below the bootstrap css; I tried adding #spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/ to my application.properties.

I have just started using intellij for an assignment and even though editing the css isn't required, I would still like to figure out how to do it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you verified whether the browser is able to _load_ your custom CSS from the URL you specified, in the first place? Check browser console & network panel for 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The browser console error message helped. My path for the css file wasn't correct.